# Binding data in DevExpress Treelist from database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, devexpress, treelist

In my project i have a `UserControl` named SubControl. In that UserControl which contains `TreeList` and two `Button`. the button used to focus the next and previous row of the treelist.

In another project I have another UserControl named MainControl various controls and Here i'm using the SubControl.

What my problem is, From MainControl i can't able to bind the data into the treelist from the database.

```
SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=source; Initial Catalog=dbname; Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand ad = new SqlCommand("Select* from mytablename", SqlCon);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(ad);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        da.Fill(ds);

        SubControl.DataSource = ds; 
        SubControl.DataBindings();
```

How can i achieve this. Helps appreciated

Comment: DataSource property of SubControl is of type string. So you can not assign dataset to string. Can you share the code of SubControl class? How are you using DataSource property of it to populate the Tree?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I created Object type property for DataSource

Comment: How are you creating treeview using DataSource property?

Comment: I dont have any code ...I simply add the TreeList in Usercontrol. then i add this usercontrol into another user control. in that 2nd usercontrol i need to bind the data to the treelist

Comment: Well in that case the answer below should help you. If you know which column to use as ValueMember and which column to use as DisplayMember I then it's pretty much simple. Did you try the approach explained in the answer?

Comment: I have only one table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145019/discussion-between-user6667769-and-chetan-ranpariya).

Comment: i have a usercontrol which is having Treelist. and im using the usercontrol from another usercontrol. is it possible to bind data from here> @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Yes you can bind it. Use the answer provided below to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind to the DataTable, not the DataSet.

```
SubControl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

From DevExpress:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q520794

> In order to create the tree list hierarchical structure, it's
>   necessary to **specify two additional fields** in the source DataTable.
>   The first field must store the nodes' unique IDs (in most cases, there
>   is already a primary key in the DataTable). The other field must
>   contain the parent node's ID for each node. To specify these fields
>   for the TreeList control, use the TreeList.KeyFieldName and
>   TreeList.ParentFieldName properties. Please refer to the following
>   help article for more information in this regard: Tree Generation
>   Algorithm in the XtraTreeList.

Comment: Hey actually i'm using TreeList. There is no child node in my table in database. I need to simply bind the data in Treelist

Comment: Is that a 3rd party control?

Comment: Yes , Its DevExpress TreeList

Comment: You have to bind to the DataTable, not the DataSet. I'll have to update my answer as I missed the fact it was a TreeList.

Comment: @User6667769 I've updated my answer. I've used DevExpress before. Nice control library. See the notes from them regarding the two additional fields required.

Comment: thanks for your involve, Hey i can easily bind the data for treelist i mean which is placed alone. But here  the treelist placed in usercontrol so it can't able to get the keyfield and parentfield

Comment: Did you try binding to the DataTable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145022/discussion-between-user6667769-and-william-xifaras).